# Using Green's theorem to evaluate line integral with circumference of an ellipse as path

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Use Green's Theorem to evaluate the line integral:

$\int_C(y-x)dx + (2x-y)dy$

for given path:

$C:x=2cos(\theta),y=sin(\theta),0\le\theta\le2\pi$

Since $0$ and $2\pi$ are the same, won't the integral evaluate to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the vector field is not conservative. Note that we have 
$$
\partial_y(y-x)=1\ne 2=\partial_x(2x-y)
$$
a necessary condition for a vector field being conservative.

Indeed, by Green's theorem, with $D$ the area enclosed by the ellipse, the integral is equal to 
$$
\int\int_{D}(Q_x-P_y)\mathrm dA=\int\int_{D}\mathrm dA=2\pi
$$

edit: Deriving the area of this ellipse, use the change of coordinates
$$
(x,y)\mapsto (2r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)
$$
with Jacobian 
$$
2r
$$
instead of $r$, the integral is
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^12r\mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta=2\pi
$$

Comment: Is there any way you can show the math lead to the answer $2\pi$?

Comment: it's the area of an ellipse with major axis 2 and minor axis 1. You can go through the computation or just remember the formula

Comment: I would have just gone through the computation except that I am not entirely sure how to set up the integral